# Set ODataValidationSettings (e.g MaxNodeCount) globally in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Is there a way to set properties from [ODataValidationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odatavalidationsettings(v=vs.118).aspx) globally in ASP.NET Web API?

I want to change [MaxNodeCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odatavalidationsettings.maxnodecount%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#P:System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataValidationSettings.MaxNodeCount) for all my controllers and looking for a way to do it during global OData configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

    config
        .Select()
        .Expand()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy()
        .MaxTop(null)
        .Count()
        // Looking for something like this:
        .MaxNodeCount(20)
        // Or like this:
        .SetDefaultODataValidationSettings(new ODataValidationSettings {MaxNodeCount = 20});
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ИванКостяшов unfortunately - no. We ended up using [MaxNodeCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt135360(v=vs.118)) in particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to accomplish this with [ASP.NET Core OData 8.x](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData).

Create a custom `ODataQueryValidator` class which implements the validation settings you wish to apply

```csharp
public class SalesforceODataQueryValidator : ODataQueryValidator
{
    public override void Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
    {
        validationSettings.MaxNodeCount = 300; // salesforce screens can exceed the default of 100 nodes per query
        base.Validate(options, validationSettings);
    }
}
```

Register this class as an implementation of `IODataQueryValidator` while setting up OData

```csharp
builder.Services.AddOData(opt => {
    opt.EnableQueryFeatures()
       .AddRouteComponents("odata", edmModel, 
       odataServices => { 
          odataServices.AddSingleton<IODataQueryValidator, SalesforceODataQueryValidator>(); 
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though the issue isn't relevant to me anymore, and I don't have a project to validate the proposed solution quickly, I'm sure your answer will help others who struggle with this issue.